# Ajax in rails, still redirecting to new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have the following code in ruby 1.9 rails 3.2.  I've followed a few different webpages to try to update a sub-field within a page.  For some reason it's still redirecting to a new page, but it's not using the layout to render ... which is strange.

Routes:

```
match 'search' => 'content#search'
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'search'},:id => 'searchForm',:remote => true, :update => "ajaxstuffhere", :position => :bottom) do %>
 <p>
                     <label id="parkname">Park Name:</label><br/> 
                     <%= text_field :search, :parkname, :size => 25 %>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                     <label id="stateprovince">State / Province:</label><br/>
                     <% tstate = State.new %>
                     <% tstate.name = "Select a State / Province" %>
                     <% @states = [] %>
                     <% @states << tstate %>
                     <% states = State.all.sort{|x,y| [x.country_id, x.name] <=> [y.country_id, y.name] } %>
                     <% states.each do |state| %>
                        <% @states << state %>
                     <% end %>
                     <%= puts "statelist is : " + @states.inspect.to_s %> 
                     <%= collection_select(:search, :state, @states, :id, :name) %>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                     <label id="zipcode">Zip Code:</label><br/> 
                     <%= text_field :search, :zipcode, :size => 5 %>

                  </p>
                  <p>
                     <label id="distanceSearchLabel">Max Distance:</label><br/>

                    <select id="distancePick" name="search[distance]">
                      <option value="">Select Distance</option>
                      <option value="10">10km</option>
                      <option value="50">50km</option>
                      <option value="100">100km</option>
                      <option value="250">250km</option>
                      <option value="500">500km</option>
                      <option value="1000">1000km</option>
                    </select>
                  </p>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
                  </p>

               <div style="clear:both;">

                </div>


            <h2>Narrow your Search</h2>


            <a href="JavaScript:amenitiesPopup()">By Amenities</a>
            <br />

            <p>
               <label id="parkname">Price:</label><br/> 
               <%= text_field :search, :pricelow, :size => 5 %>
               <%= text_field :search, :pricehigh, :size => 5 %>
            </p>
            <p>
               <label id="parkname">Age:</label><br/> 
               <%= text_field :search, :age, :size => 5 %>
            </p>
            <p>

            <%= check_box :search,:pets_allowed %><label id="petsallowedcb">Allows Pets</label><br/> 
            </p>

            <%= check_box :search,:big_rigs %><label id="bigrigcb">Allows Big Rigs</label><br/> 

            <p>
            <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
          </p>
          <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def search
    ...
   render :partial => 'search'
end #seach def
```

I have an empty div within the html page with ID "ajaxstuffhere".  When I click the submit button on the form, it loads the _search.html.erb in a new page instead of in the specified div.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:  Here is the post request from the server :

```
Started POST "/search" for 70.28.21.25 at 2013-09-25 13:22:54 +0000
Processing by ContentController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "search"=>{"parkname"=>"as", "state"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "distance"=>"", "pricelow"=>"", "pricehigh"=>"", "age"=>"", "pets_allowed"=>"0", "big_rigs"=>"0"}}
Rendered content/_search.html.erb (424.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 637ms (Views: 105.6ms | ActiveRecord: 478.6ms)
```

Also, the HTML rendering of the form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" data-remote="true" id="searchForm" method="post" position="bottom" update="ajaxstuffhere"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

                  <p>
                     <label id="parkname">Park Name:</label><br/> 
                     <input id="search_parkname" name="search[parkname]" size="25" type="text" />
                  </p>
...
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Edit:  1 week later and still not functional

I have a new homepage.js.erb file with the following:

```
("#ajaxstuffhere").hide();
```

Which allegedly is supposed to be returned and executed when `data-remote="true"` is set on the form.  Note that I switched to the homepage controller until I can get an ajax response working.....

Well ... that didn't work so I tried a coffee script alternative:

```
<script>
$(document).ready ->
  $("#ajaxstuffhere").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#ajaxstuffhere").append "<p>RESPONSE</p>" //xhr.responseText
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#ajaxstuffhere").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
</script>
```

I dropped this right in the body of the html.erb file.  It should get executed when the page loads, I would think?

At any rate, if the data-remote="true" tag did the ajax request, the response should just add "response" to the ajaxstuffhere field ... except this is not the case.  The page still reloads and the AJAX response is probably lost

Comment: it is submitting the form via `html` format. do you have `rails.js` installed?

Comment: according to a website I looked at, the javascript comes from the javascript_include_tag :default in the containing page's layout.  Edit:  according to the page's source, only assets/default.js has been loaded

Comment: it loads the default js files if present, if you do not have those files in your app then it will not load them.

Comment: right now its loading prototype, effects, dragdrop, controls.  It seems to compile them into one big javascript file for the include.  At any rate, it's still loading in a new page

Comment: u need `rails.js` as well.. see [here](https://github.com/overture8/prototype-rails3-ujs/tree/master/public/javascripts)

Comment: Thanks for the post.  Unfortunately it's still not disabling the normal post call.  Do I need respond_to in the controller in rails 3?

Comment: you will need that but that is not the current issue  as it is calling the action with html format...try showing the rails server log for request, it might help someone to debug it.

Comment: Submitted log.  Maybe it's worth mentioning that I include :application.js and not default.js?  All of the files are linked through there, as default.js is missing from the root folder for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have a line :

```
<%= render :partial => '/inc/analytics' %>
```

For Google Analytics, inside of the layout.  During a post request, the line forced the page to navigate to a new page.

I have no idea why this is the case, perhaps google has some kind of actionlistener that overrides the one that rails puts on for remote forms.

Any more information related to this is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Is your submit button in the right place?  This would be easier with a code snippet of the view with the form.